# How to install pymysql.cursors package in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, python

I have install that, and the following error was generated:

```
>>> import pymysql.cursors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pymysql.cursors
```

Comment: How did you install the package?

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pip  
python -m pip install --user PyMySQL
```

Start the Python interpreter by typing the command `python` and test it by running:

```
import pymysql.cursors
```

Answer (score 2):

To install `PyMySQL` on your Ubuntu just do that

first, change your user to root user with:

> sudo -i

then using pip, download PyMySQL with:

> pip install PyMySQL

This assume pip is already installed.